# Using jQWidgets in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, jqwidget

I'd like to use the jqxGrid widget in an Aurelia project, but I'm not sure how to adapt their example (below) to work in an Aurelia View/View-Model component.

See it run [here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/bindingtoarray.htm).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title id='Description'>This example shows how to create a Grid from Array data.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // prepare the data
            var data = new Array();
            var firstNames =
            [
                "Andrew", "Nancy", "Shelley", "Regina", "Yoshi", "Antoni", "Mayumi", "Ian", "Peter", "Lars", "Petra", "Martin", "Sven", "Elio", "Beate", "Cheryl", "Michael", "Guylene"
            ];
            var lastNames =
            [
                "Fuller", "Davolio", "Burke", "Murphy", "Nagase", "Saavedra", "Ohno", "Devling", "Wilson", "Peterson", "Winkler", "Bein", "Petersen", "Rossi", "Vileid", "Saylor", "Bjorn", "Nodier"
            ];
            var productNames =
            [
                "Black Tea", "Green Tea", "Caffe Espresso", "Doubleshot Espresso", "Caffe Latte", "White Chocolate Mocha", "Cramel Latte", "Caffe Americano", "Cappuccino", "Espresso Truffle", "Espresso con Panna", "Peppermint Mocha Twist"
            ];
            var priceValues =
            [
                "2.25", "1.5", "3.0", "3.3", "4.5", "3.6", "3.8", "2.5", "5.0", "1.75", "3.25", "4.0"
            ];
            for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                var row = {};
                var productindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * productNames.length);
                var price = parseFloat(priceValues[productindex]);
                var quantity = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
                row["firstname"] = firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)];
                row["lastname"] = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
                row["productname"] = productNames[productindex];
                row["price"] = price;
                row["quantity"] = quantity;
                row["total"] = price * quantity;
                data[i] = row;
            }
            var source =
            {
                localdata: data,
                datatype: "array",
                datafields:
                [
                    { name: 'firstname', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'lastname', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'productname', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'quantity', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'price', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'total', type: 'number' }
                ]
            };
            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 850,
                source: dataAdapter,
                columnsresize: true,
                columns: [
                  { text: 'Name', datafield: 'firstname', width: 120 },
                  { text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'lastname', width: 120 },
                  { text: 'Product', datafield: 'productname', width: 180 },
                  { text: 'Quantity', datafield: 'quantity', width: 80, cellsalign: 'right' },
                  { text: 'Unit Price', datafield: 'price', width: 90, cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2' },
                  { text: 'Total', datafield: 'total', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2' }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id='jqxWidget'>
        <div id="jqxgrid">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the example above, everything is done through HTML script tags, which don't seem to work in the HTML template elements used in Aurelia Views.  I assume I'd have to import the required jqwidgets files into the View-Model with JSPM, but I haven't the slightest idea how to do that.

Could anyone help me figure out how to wire up the above example code into an Aurelia component? (If it helps, I have an empty, editable Aurelia project skeleton running here https://gist.run/?id=6f38a1211eeecafe74c4dd4c960fc2d6&sha=d9959ac0f4d7ad9f3c8385b7b78f648adfc91e11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample app based on the aurelia-skeleton-navigation, you can find this [here](https://github.com/JeroenVinke/aurelia-jqxgrid-sample-app). Let me walk you through the relevant steps.

First you need to install the jqwidgets: `jspm install jqwidgets=github:jqwidgets/jQWidgets`

Make sure that you have install JSPM's `css` plugin as well: `jspm install css`.

In [app.html](https://github.com/JeroenVinke/aurelia-jqxgrid-sample-app/blob/master/src/app.html#L4) we can load the CSS part of jqwidgets: `<require from="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css!"></require>`. Note the exclamation mark at the end, which instructs SystemJS to load the css file using the `css` plugin. This

Then you could create a `my-grid` custom element by creating two files: `my-grid.html` and `my-grid.js`.

my-grid.html could look something like:

```
<template>
  <div ref="container"></div>
</template>
```

Here you see the `ref` attribute, which is Aurelia-specific code, and it will create a property called `container` on the view-model (my-grid.js), containing a reference to the `div` element. This is very handy as we can use this reference to initialize the grid without having to use jQuery.

creating my-grid.js is a little bit more work

```
import 'jquery';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcore';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxdata';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxmenu';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.aggregates';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsreorder';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.edit';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.export';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.grouping';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.pager';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort';
import 'jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.storage';
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyGridCustomElement {
  @bindable gridData;

  attached() {
    let source = {
      localdata: this.gridData,
      datatype: 'array',
      datafields:
      [
          { name: 'firstname', type: 'string' },
          { name: 'lastname', type: 'string' },
          { name: 'productname', type: 'string' },
          { name: 'quantity', type: 'number' },
          { name: 'price', type: 'number' },
          { name: 'total', type: 'number' }
      ]
    };

    let dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

    $(this.container).jqxGrid({
      width: 850,
      source: dataAdapter,
      columnsresize: true,
      columns: [
        { text: 'Name', datafield: 'firstname', width: 120 },
        { text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'lastname', width: 120 },
        { text: 'Product', datafield: 'productname', width: 180 },
        { text: 'Quantity', datafield: 'quantity', width: 80, cellsalign: 'right' },
        { text: 'Unit Price', datafield: 'price', width: 90, cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2' },
        { text: 'Total', datafield: 'total', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2' }
      ]
    });
  }
}
```

A few things are happening here. First, using Aurelia's naming conventions when naming the class `MyGridCustomElement`, we can use this custom element with `<my-grid>`.

Another thing you see is the large amount of `import` statements. This will pull in all parts of the jqxgrid. We need to tell JSPM to load these modules as `Global`, as JSPM will try and load these as AMD which will not work.

Since we'd like to pass data to the `<my-grid>` custom element, we need to set up a property that we can then bind to. This can be done by decorating a with the `@bindable` decorator.

It is recommended to initialize jQuery components from the `attached()` lifecycle callback. In `my-grid.html` we added the `ref="container"` attribute, which allows us to initialize the grid from the view-model using the `container` property: `$(this.container).jqxGrid({`.

At this point the `<my-grid>` custom element is set up and we can start using it.

In any view, and I have chosen to do this in the [`welcome.html`](https://github.com/JeroenVinke/aurelia-jqxgrid-sample-app/blob/master/src/welcome.html) view, the following will allow you to use the `<my-grid>` custom element:

```
<template>
  <require from="./my-grid"></require>

  <my-grid grid-data.bind="data"></my-grid>
</template>
```

The `<require>` tag will pull in our custom element so that we can use it from this view. We would now like to pass some data to this custom element. In `my-grid.js` we declared a property `@bindable` which was the `gridData` property. Here we must convert it to kebab-case (`gridData` -> `grid-data`). And we databind the `gridData` property to the `data` property which exists in the [`welcome.js`](https://github.com/JeroenVinke/aurelia-jqxgrid-sample-app/blob/master/src/welcome.js) file.

At this point we should be done, although we need to instruct JSPM to load jqxgrid using the Global module format (as it does not load correctly using the default AMD format). You can see the necessary configuration to do so in [config.js](https://github.com/JeroenVinke/aurelia-jqxgrid-sample-app/blob/master/config.js#L10-L14).

Comment: Absolutely fantastic!  Thank you so much!!!  I just have two questions about what you did: 1) why do you use the JSPM css plugin to "require" the css rather than just using a <link> element? (I've never seen the css plugin used before and so I'm not sure how it differs from loading in css the usual way); and 2) you say that by adding a "ref" property to the div that it allows you to not have to use jQuery, but doesn't `$(this.container).jqxGrid({` still use jQuery just as much as doing something like `$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({`?  Is there a substantial difference between those two approaches?

Comment: 1) You could use a link tag as well, but I prefer to load CSS through the module loader, but you will need to use the css plugin so that it "fixes" the paths inside the CSS file.

2) Yep, you are still using jQuery, but whenever I can I like to avoid jQuery. And using the `ref` attribute allows you to use less jQuery

Comment: Also note that using `<require>` enables the jspm bundler to add the styles to the bundle.